# MySQL Limit By Second Table

Tags: mysql, join, limit

I've got a database with events and organizations that run those events. I am looking to create a query that shows any organization that has not created an event in 90 days or more.

So far, I have this query:

```
SELECT organizations.name, organizations.first_name, organizations.last_name, 
organizations.email, events.created_at, events.start_date, events.end_date
FROM events
INNER JOIN organizations ON events.organizer_id = organizations.id
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 90 DAY) > events.created_at
GROUP BY events.organizer_id
ORDER BY events.created_at DESC
```

The problem is that this will just choose any event that is more than 90 days old, but not the latest event. How do I get the query to look at the event with the newest created_at and see if that is 90 days or older and include only that?

Comment: Since you're looking for organizations, then your query should select from organizations not from events, And it should use a left join instead of inner join in order to show organizations that did not post any events at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation.  If you care about organizations, then you don't need `event` information in the `select`:

```
SELECT o.name, o.first_name, o.last_name, o.email
FROM events e INNER JOIN
     organizations o
     ON e.organizer_id = o.id
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) > MAX(e.created_at)
ORDER BY MAX(e.created_at) DESC;
```

This query will not select organizations that never have events.  To do that, you need a `left outer join`.  Here is one way:

```
SELECT o.name, o.first_name, o.last_name, o.email
FROM organizations o LEFT JOIN
     events e
     ON e.organizer_id = o.id AND
        e.created_at >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
WHERE e.organizer_id is null
GROUP BY o.id
ORDER BY MAX(e.created_at) DESC;
```

Note that I also changed the query to use table aliases.  These make the query easier to write and read.

Comment: This worked great, thanks! For anyone looking in the future, I did want to show last created date in which case you can add MAX(e.created_at) in the select to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First create a query (call it "A" here) that selects all organiazations which created an event in the last 90 days.

```
SELECT organizer_id from events where DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 90 DAY) <= events.created_at
```

Then write a query which lists all organizations which are not in the result set of query A:

```
SELECT * from organizations where id not in (A)
```

Which makes it to:

```
SELECT * from organizations where id not in (SELECT organizer_id from events where DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 90 DAY) <= events.created_at)
```

This works because SQL is "orthogonal", i.e., you can embed queries into other queries.